# С помощью JQuery разобрать строку в <p> на две подстроки и каждую поместить в созданный элемент DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть группа элементов `<p>` каждый из которых содержит строку вида "название: значение". Надо каждый элемент разделить по сепаратору ":". Потом, допустим, создать элемент `<dl>` с  `<dt>` внутри и поместить в него левое значение. Правое значение поместить в элемент `<dd>` этого же `<dl>`. И так для каждого `<p>` в наборе. А потом удалить все элементы `<p>` этого набора, но оставить созданные списки описаний.

```html
<dl>
<dt>Термин 1</dt>
<dd>Описание термина 1</dd>
<dt>Термин 2</dt>
<dd>Описание термина 2</dd>
</dl>
```

Обертываю нужный набор `<p>`, методу each() передаю функцию, в которой текущий `<p>` split'ом распиливаю по ":". Но дальше ничего не выходит.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Приведите пример того, как вы это делаете

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте, попробуйте продебажить следующий код:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="set-p">
        <p>Термин 1: Описание термина 1</p>
        <p>Термин 2: Описание термина 2</p>
        <p>Термин 3: Описание термина 3</p>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    debugger;
    var dl = '<dl>';
    $('#set-p p').each(function () {
        var val = $(this).text();
        if (val) {
            var arr = val.split(': ');
            if (arr.length >= 2) {
                dl += '<dt>' + arr[0] + '</dt>';
                dl += '<dd>' + arr[1] + '</dd>';
            }
        }
    });
    dl += '</dl>';
    $('#set-p').replaceWith(dl);
});
</script>
```

Comment: сначала вообще все `<p>` заменялись на один `<dl>`. Я добавила в $('#set-p p').replaceWith(dl). Он у меня `<p>` заменил `<dl>`, но они пустые.

Comment: Прошу вас показать свой код, а именно: часть html, которая используется в js и сам js. Жду что-то подобное, что я вам прислал.

Comment: Вот разметка:                                                       
    `<div class="container">
        <p>Характеристики</p>
        <p>Производитель: УМК</p>
 <p>Диаметр: 115</p>
 <p>Толщина: 0,5мм</p>
 <p>Утепленный: нет</p>
    </div>`

Comment: Js тот же, за исключением имен переменных.

Comment: Все-таки советую вам воспользоваться моим примером, при этом продебажить код. И разобраться как он работает.

Answer (score 0):

Решила сделать следующим образом, все работает:

```
$(function() {

    var allValues = [];

    $('.description p').each(function() {
        var currentItem = $(this).text();

        if (currentItem) {
            var splitItem = currentItem.split(':');
            allValues.push(splitItem);
        }
        var dl = '<dl>';
        $(this).replaceWith(dl);
    });

    $('.description dl').each(function() {
        var currentStr = '<dt>' + allValues[0][0] + '</dt>' + '<dd>' + allValues[0][1] + '</dd>';
        $(this).html(currentStr);
        allValues.shift(0);
    });
});
```

Comment: В вашем коде два each, мой содержит только один.

Comment: @mursalov-oleg Ваш не работает, а мой работает. Можно и оптимизировать.

Comment: Прошу Вас показать, как Вы проверили, что мой код не работает?